# mkdir: cannot create directory: No such file or directory

Tags: bash

What's wrong with the commands below?

```
$ var1="~/Music/$(date +%d%m%y)"
$ echo "$var1"
~/Music/240118
$ mkdir "$var1"
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘~/Music/240118’: No such file or directory
```

However

```
$ mkdir ~/Music/240118
```

works.

Never thought I would ask such questions after years of using bash...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tilde expansion doesn't work after the variable is expanded, so if you put a literal tilde in `var`, it will end up as a literal tilde to `mkdir`. (Note how the error message from `mkdir` has a literal tilde in it, not the actual path of your home directory.)

And, since you put the tilde in quotes in the assignment, it doesn't expand there either. If it's not in quotes, it does:

```
$ var="~/Music"; echo $var
~/Music
$ var=~/"Music"; echo $var
/home/me/Music
```

Of course, you could always just use `$HOME` instead:

```
$ var="$HOME/Music"; echo $var
/home/me/Music
```

Comment: Thanks. However I've noticed that this works either:
$ var1=~/Music/"$(date +%d%m%y)"
$ mkdir "$var1"