# No such file, but file is just created

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I've got a bash script in which i create a file and append to it.
Problem is when I try to write to it, the shell tells me

```
/home/username/bin/myscript: line 62: ~/Desktop/folder/filename: No such file or directory
```

The script part is:

```
57: mkdir ~/Desktop/folder
58: touch -a ~/Desktop/folder/$1
59: chmod 774 ~/Desktop/folder/$1

61: addr=$(cat $D/$1/address)
62: echo "$addr">>"~/Desktop/folder/$1"
```

When I go look for the file, it appears in the ls command with the correct permissions. It also appears correctly in the file explorer.

I've tried changing between `cat` and `echo` commands to append to the file but neither works.

Comment: See this similar question: [mkdir: cannot create directory: No such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/419448/mkdir-cannot-create-directory-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this on line 62:

```
$ echo "$addr" >> ~/Desktop/folder/"$1"
```

Comment: To explain, the original problem is that ~ doesn't expand to your actual home directory when it's inside quotes. Moving the ~ outside of the quoted section fixes it.